# Prolog predicates

Tags: prolog, predicates

I am currently learning about predicate logic in Prolog. I am having trouble answering a question on the topic and would like to know the steps one one take to solve such a question using Prolog predicates. I have a scenario which must be represented in Prolog predicates using  only two different predicate names.

1. A and B are married
2. B likes C
3. C and D are married
4. D likes E
5. F likes B
6. E likes B
7. E and G are married
8. A likes G

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for asking such a question, perhaps.

Comment: @CiaranG No, this is the right place for questions like this about Prolog programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write down what it says.

```
are_married(a,b).

likes(b,c).
```

And so on. We've used two names of predicates so far.

In Prolog, atoms are denoted by identifiers starting with a lower case letter. Identifiers starting with an upper case letter or an underscore `_` denote logical variables.

Comment: Could  they all be placed in two predicates?
E.g
are_married((a,b),(c,d),(e,g)).

Comment: @DrKhan no, thats not how Prolog works. You could of course define another predicate, `married_couples([ (a,b), (c,d), (e,f) ]).`. But then to get one married couple you'd have to spend some work.

Comment: Would this be correct for the following, I produced two predicates: <br> 
1. is_married([a,b],[c,d],[e,g]).  
2. likes([b,c],[d,e],[f,b],[e,b],[a,g]).

Comment: @DrKhan I don't know what you mean by that. If you could formulate more fully the background and describe what you need, then you can post a new question with all that. :)