# Creating Prolog Predicates

Tags: prolog, predicates

[Prolog predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502892/prolog-predicates) - Built on this, question did not have enough clarity so I am posting the question in context.

Here is the question and I will post what I have done so far and what I am struggling on.

### Scenario (A quiet weird one)

James and Victoria are married, but Victoria is in love with Curt. Curt does not love her because he is still married to and cares about Kylie, though she is more interested in Henry. Arthur is romantically inclined towards Victoria but he is in competition with Henry, who also loves Victoria despite being married to Crystal, whom James is feeling romantic about.

1] Represent this information using Prolog predicates.Only use two predicate names.

**This is my interpretation of this**

is_Married([James,Victoria],[Curt,Kylie],[Henry,Crystal]).

is_inLove([Victoria,Curt],[Kylie,Henry],[Arthur,Victoria],[Henry,Victoria],[James,Victoria]).

For the second predicate, I'm also unsure if I should put [Curt,Kylie] as it said 'and still cares about' in the scenario.

2] A married is on the rocks if both participants are romantically inclined towards other people, and not each other. How could a Prolog rule represent this statement.

**My answer**

∀∃x: is_married(X,Y) ∧¬ is_inLove(X,Y) ∨ is_inLove(Y,X) → on_rocks (x)

I'm a bit confused on how to represent, marriage as apposed to the two participants.

3]A circle of love exists when a person X loves someone else, who in turn loves somebody else and so on until somebody in that chain loves person X. Assuming only one circle of love exists, write the prolog rules that will find this circle and produce a list of those involved.

**My answer**

write_list([X|A,B,C]:-

write(X)

writelist(X,Tail).

Comment: Read a tutorial, this is too basic to be a useful question (and you seem to ignore the answers to your previous question). Look at Adventure in Prolog by Amzi!inc or Learn Prolog Now!

Comment: you really should study the tutorials first in a systematic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Prolog way is to **represent each pair as a separate fact**; all the similar facts will form **a relationship** (*`predicate`*).

So you have three `is_Married` facts, and five `loves` facts. Or six, including that one about Curt:

```
is_Married(James,Victoria).
is_Married(Curt,Kylie).
is_Married(Henry,Crystal).

loves(Victoria,Curt).       % changed the name
loves(Kylie,Henry).       
loves(Arthur,Victoria).
loves(Henry,Victoria).
loves(James,Victoria).
loves(Curt,Kylie).
```

"A marri[age] is on the rocks if both participants are romantically inclined towards other people, and not each other." This is a straightforward translation from English to Prolog:

```
on_the_rocks(A,B):-     % a pair of people, whose marriage is on the rocks
   is_Married(A,B), 
   loves(A,C), C \= B,
   .....
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear descriptions Will Ness, question 3 wants to find the people involve and then list them. I will edit the origonal to attempt it

Comment: @DrKhan it's not proper for me to just give you the answer to your homework. :)

Comment: It's not homework, I'm revising topics for an exam and it is practice questions, but I understand